# Generate JIRA release note through a jenkins job without plugins

Tags: jenkins, jira, release

I know that this is possible through the [JIRA-JENKINS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin). But I'm not an administrative user neither in `JIRA` nor `Jenkins`. Therefore I want to know is it possible to generate `JIRA` release note through a `jenkin` job without installing any plugins to `JIRA` or `JENKINS`?

Comment: If you have no access to modify either configuration, how do you propose you do that? You can write your own parser that looks through the build log for source control comments and compiles a list of mentioned JIRA issues...

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I did it just now, here is my solution (that is a mix of several partial solution I have found googling):

In your deploy jobs, add a shell execution step at the end of the job and replace all parameters of the following script with correct values

```
version=<your_jira_version> ##(for example 1.0.71)

project_name=<your_jira_project_key> ##(for example PRJ)

jira_version_id=$(curl --silent -u <jira_user>:<jira_password> -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://<your_jira_url>/rest/api/2/project/${project_name}/versions" | jq "map(select(.[\"name\"] == \"$version\")) | .[0] | .id" | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//')

project_id=$(curl --silent -u <jira_user>:<jira_password> -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://<your_jira_url>/rest/api/2/project/${project_name}" | jq .id | sed -e 's/^"//'  -e 's/"$//')

release_notes_page="https://<your_jira_url>/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=${jira_version_id}&styleName=Text&projectId=${project_id}"

release_notes=$(curl --silent -D- -u <jira_user>:<jira_password> -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$release_notes_page")

rm -rf releasenotes.txt

echo "$release_notes" | sed -n "/<textarea rows=\"40\" cols=\"120\">/,/<\/textarea>/p" | grep -v "textarea" > releasenotes.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution! Just 2 remarks:

1) `project_id` request can be redundant as u can extract id from `jira_version_id` together with `version_id`

2) `echo "$release_notes" | sed -n "/<textarea rows=\"40\" cols=\"120\">/,/<\/textarea>/p" | grep -v "textarea" > releasenotes.txt` can be enhanced with cutting new lines by piping `| grep -v -e '^$'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the maven-changes-plugin. You have to create a small maven project (doesn't need any sources) and include the plugin in the plugins section with the necessary configuration (see here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/jira-report-mojo.html)

Then you create a Jenkins job, and just execute the maven goals you need (most probably just "mvn changes:jira-report").